# find the path of a file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, path

Hello I would like to locate the file `'my_file.mat'` that should be somewhere inside the folder `'C:\...\mypath\folder1'`.

the folder `folder1` contains several subfolders and the file `my_file` could be in any of these subfolders.
I would like to retrieve its full path.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [which](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) function.

```
mypath = which('my_file.mat')
```

As commented below, this assumes that your 'folder1' has been added to your search path. To add (and remove if no longer needed) 'folder1' to your search path:

```
my_folder_path = 'path/to/folder1'
addpath(genpath(my_folder_path))
mypath = which('my_file.mat')   
rmpath(my_folder_path)
```

Comment: This works only when file, to be searched, is on the MATLAB path or in the current working folder !

Comment: True. I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `genpath` and `which` combo:

```
addpath(genpath(folderName));
which test.txt -all

>>
Z:\home\**\Documents\MATLAB\R2010b\bin\test.txt
```